# How do I get HUD to work with GTK2 apps

Tags: gtk, hud

I have a program which uses GTK2 that I want to integrate with HUD called Stata 12.

The menus are correctly located in the appmenu, but the menus do not show up in the HUD.

When I do use HUD and try to search through the menus, the HUD searches other open applications or system settings, but not Stata itself.

Is there a way I can get it to integrate?

Photos:

Apps in the appmenu being placed right: [image: http://i.imgur.com/RRQkA.png]

HUD showing none of the options in the menu: [image: http://i.imgur.com/Ctx9i.png]

Comment: Is there any reason why you added ">"?

Comment: We need some more information from you if not this question will be closed (you have also not logged in since asking).

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons but make sure /usr/share/applications has a .desktop file for the application. HUD needs that. There are good instructions for intalling this app on Ubuntu at http://eduardgrebe.net/2012/10/installing-stata-12-on-ubuntu-12-04/